# Datatable data bind with textbox

Tags: c#, data-binding

need to get value from datatable and bind the value to textbox

```
            DataTable ff = new DataTable();
            DataColumn Regno = new DataColumn("Regno");
            ff.Columns.Add(Regno);
            DataRow row = ff.NewRow();
            var rg = (from data in db.receipts
                      select data.Regno).Max();

            row["Regno"] = rg + 1;
            ff.Rows.Add(row);
            txt_reciptno.DataBindings.Add("text", row, "Regno");
```

Comment: why you wanna do that ? why don't just assign the text_recpitno.Text = (rg + 1).ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why  are you using DataTable ??  you can simply get `rg` via your query and then set the text property to rg + 1, something like following:

```
 text_recpitno.Text = (rg + 1).ToString();
```

Comment: I think he just create a simple sample to ask how to use DataBindings.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Habib.OSU.  But for the binding, try this:

```
txt_reciptno.DataBindings.Add("text", ff.DefaultView, "Regno");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this article could help you. [Data Binding in .Net](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html)

And in your case you need

```
txt_reciptno.DataBindings.Add("Text", ff, "Regno");
```

If you want to move to the next row , you should use

```
 var myCurrencyManager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[ff];

 myCurrencyManager.Position ++;
```